# Separate static function into another (header?) file in C

Tags: c, header-files

I'm learning how to program in C and came across the following issue. I have some private helper functions that I would not like to expose anywhere. Here is how source files look like:

`logic.h`:

```
#ifndef LOGIC_H
#define LOGIC_H

enum logic_type{
    customer_logic = 1,
    requestor_logic,
    company_logic
}

void execute_logic(enum logic_type logic_type);

#endif //LOGIC_H
```

`logic.c`:

```
#include "logic.h"

static void _execute_customer_logic();
static void _execute_requestor_logic();
static void _execute_company_logic();

void execute_logic(enum logic_type logic_type){
    switch(logic_type){
        case customer_logic:
            _execute_customer_logic();
            break;
        case requestor_logic:
            _execute_requestor_logic();
            break;
        case company_logic:
            _execute_company_logic();
            break;
    }
}

void _execute_customer_logic(){
    //very long and complicated function
}

void _execute_requestor_logic(){
    //very long and complicated function
}

void _execute_company_logic(){
    //very long and complicated function
}
```

With the current design it looks really messy. So I was thinking about putting each logic in a separate private header file and then simply include it. Like

`company_logic_internal.h`:

```
#ifndef COMPANY_LOGIC_INTERNAL_H
#define COMPANY_LOGIC_INTERNAL_H

    void _execute_company_logic(){
        //very long and complicated function
    }

#endif //COMPANY_LOGIC_INTERNAL_H
```

The problem is that I put an implementation into the header file which looks contradictory to the definition of header files which contains function prototypes, but not the actual definition. Making this `company_logic.h` to be a `company_logic.c` also looks wierd since it means that `.c` file will be included.

So I'm kind of confused of how to implement such a thing better.

Comment: Well, of course it is contradictory. If you put the "definitions" in the header file, every function that implements that header will compile the function with the same name. This will result in multiple instances of the function SYMBOL during compilation and a linker-error for `"multiple definition of the_function.."`

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin That's why I made them to have internal-linkage. To avoid such link error.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin So will the static function definition in the header file help? Or maybe there is another way to go?

Comment: The problem there is that if you properly protect against multiple inclusions of the header with proper *header-guards*, you will only have one instance of the function compiled. It's a really wonky way to try and factor code that is bound to end in failure as your code grows.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin Can you suggest another way of how to deal with such a thing? I personally thought that header with `static` definition with the proper header-guard was ok...

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin Ah... you are exactly right. It's extrememly wonky. I just read the Standard and found the following **N1570::6.2.2(7)**: `If, within a translation unit, the same identifier appears with both internal and external
linkage, the behavior is undefined.` So it is very easy to make things go wrong. Especially if the first declaration is `extern`, but the later declaration is `static`.

Comment: The proper way to deal with it is to include the function prototypes for functions with external linkage in the headers so they my be called in any source that includes the header and simply define functions with internal linkage in the source where they are used and do not include prototypes for them in any header.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin But if declare an identifier of a function prototype to have external linkage (in a header file) and later on (in a source file) define the function with internal linkage won't it cause UB according to the section I cited above? Could you please expand?

Comment: There is also [C11 Standard (n1570) - 6.2.2 Linkages of identifiers (note: 30)](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#note30) *"A function declaration can contain the storage-class specifier static only if it is at file scope;"*

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin I have one question. Is the behavior of the program `static void foo(); void foo(){ }; int main(int argc, char * argv[]){ }` undefined? It compiles fine, and has file-scope `static`.

Comment: Of course not...

Comment: You may be covered there by [C11 Standard (n1570) - 6.2.2 Linkages of identifiers(p4)](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.2.2p4) where *"...the linkage of the identifier at the later declaration is the same as the linkage specified at the prior declaration."* (resulting in `foo` having internal linkage despite the lack of `static` at the later declaration)

Comment: Thanks, understood! If I declare non-static first it does not compile.

Comment: In such cases, prefer `static inline` to just `static`

Answer (score 1):

This not exactly direct answer to the question, but you can try this to avoid unnecessary expose of your code and avoid recompile.

so instead of going for number of header files(.h files), go for .c files, i.e, each function can be defined in separate .c files and create `static library`(ex: company_private.a), you haven't mentioned what compiler you use but with `gcc` you can control access to the library with `visibility` option or `--exclude-libs`(though not sure it is supported with all tool chain) while compilation and link it to the program where you want use those API's.

for simple toy example of creating static library check following link
`http://www.codingfleets.com/2018/12/how-to-create-static-library-in-c.html`

if you are using gcc tool chain, you can find lot of documentation about limiting visibility of symbols online.